# Populating data from a Data Extension to a Marketing Cloud - Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I'm sure this is quite straight forward however i can't for the life of me work it out. I'm trying to output someone's first name into a cloud page (not a smart capture field)

Essentially its a response page that says Thanks %%FirstName%% for your response

The Data Extension has 3 fields (Email address, FirstName, LastName)

Code i have in email:

```
    <p><a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1045))=%%">yourPage</a></p>
```

Code i have in the Cloud Page

```
%%=AttributeValue("FirstName")=%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `FirstName` happens to be accessible from within the email, you can pass it along inside the `CloudPagesURL` function:

```
%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1045, 'FirstName', AttributeValue(FirstName)))=%%
```

...or if `FirstName` is a field in the sendable DE...

```
%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1045, 'FirstName', [FirstName]))=%%
```

Then retrieve it in the CloudPage like so:

```
%%[
var @firstName
set @firstName = RequestParameter('FirstName')
]%%
Thanks %%=v(@firstName)=%%
```

Comment: Thanks very much, option 2 worked a treat